# Accessing Master page in custom PageBase in App_Code?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am tring to access a custom property on my Master page in a custom PageBase that resides in the App_Code folder. I can get this to work no problem in a web app but im having trouble doing it in the website project.

PageBase:

```
public abstract class PageBase : ClientSidePageBase
{
    public WebMessage Message
    {
        get
        {
           if (this.Master is MainMaster)
                return ((MainMaster)this.Master).Message;
            else if (this.Master is PopupMaster)
                return ((PopupMaster)this.Master).Message;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The above sample is what is in my web application and works fine but if i try and put this in the App_Code it doesnt pick up the MasterPage class so I cant access the property.

Any ideas? Hopefully its something easy i am over looking.

Comment: Normally, don't pages usually inherit abstract classes, not the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a "Web Site" and "Web Application" is that with "Web Site", only the code in "App_Code" is compiled into a .net assembly; everything else is compiled at run-time; with "Web Application", all your code if compiled into a .net assembly.

I'm guessing that your master page is not in App_Code.  You said that the PageBase class is in App_Code.  Therefore, it sounds like you're trying to inherit a class that is compiled at run-time in a class that is pre-compiled.

I think that you need to either have your PageBase class outside of App_Code, or you need to have the code for the master page inside of App_Code.

Please let us know how you make it work.

Comment: Yup...i just figured that out after posting the question. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: im actually getting an error. 

'....' is in the special directory 'App_Code', which is not allowed.

Comment: I used an interface that the master page inherited and then from the PageBase I referenced it like this ((IWebMessage)this.Master).Msg;

Comment: @chopps, when you solved this problem, which of the files did you place in the `App_Code` folder?

Comment: I kept them all in the App_Code folder and in the Masterpage outside of the App_code folder I did this.

 Control ctrl = this.FindControl("msg");
            return (WebMessage)ctrl;